# How to listen to event made in another JS file

Tags: javascript, events, addeventlistener, custom-events

I have a button with a 'click' event listener, this event is made in 'example1.js', I need to create another event lister in 'example2.js' but the logic in this listener depends on what is returned from the first one.

example1.js:

```
button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const confirmation = confirm('Are you sure you want to do that?');

  <some code here>

});
```

example2.js:

```
button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (<confirmation from 1st listener>) {
    do some stuff here...
  }
});
```

I am aware of custom events:

```
const confirmationResponse = new CustomEvent('customEventListener', {detail: {isConfirm: confirmation}});

button.addEventListener('customEventListener', (event) => {
 console.log(event.detail)
});

button.dispatchEvent(confirmationResponse);
```

I am not sure how to implement the logic between the two files since all tutorials I found are in one file, which would make the variable accessible.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you're using classes, make it a [field](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Public_class_fields)
2. [Export](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export) the variable and import it in the second file

But before doing that, I would consider *why* you're in need to do that. If those buttons are in the same form, component, etc., they probably should sit in one class/file/etc. (my opinion)

EDIT: btw referring to title, you're not listening to another event, but reading a variable changed in another event :P